# Xcopy command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, command, xcopy

```
xcopy %SOURCE% %DESTINATION% /E
```

- Using above command am copying folders and files from source to destination.
- While copying, its showing source destination of the copied/copying file in the batch. I mean sys out is coming.
- is it possible to block it?
- Just copy has to work without showing anything in the batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XCOPY %SOURCE% %DESTINATION% /E > NUL
```

If also want avoid error messages:

```
XCOPY %SOURCE% %DESTINATION% /E > NUL 2> NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
xcopy %SOURCE% %DESTINATION% /EQ
```

If you use `>nul` , you also get no over-writing message and `Xcopy` will wait for key pressing ... endless.